# Gradle deploy : GC overhead limit exceeded (max heap: 1024 MB)

Tags: java, gradle

Error : **GC overhead limit exceeded (max heap: 1024 MB)**

Frequently am getting above error When I do gradle deploy or other gradle operations from command prompt.

Could anyone help me to fix this issue.

Project: Java

Build : Gradle

*This is related to Gradle and Java. not only JAVA

Comment: @Ravindrababu : this has be to fixed in gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked for me and Hope this will help you :

**GRADLE_OPTS=-Xmx2048m gradle deploy**

Answer (score 1):

This type of error (Error : GC overhead limit exceeded) occur by the  garbage collector, your GC is taking an excessive amount of time 98% of all CPU time of the process and recovers very little memory in each run only 2% of the heap.

You can try to turn off thi with the command :  `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit`

Comment: could you please tell me from where I have execute this command?

Comment: you can refet below stackover flow link, you can get project answer from this link : Question By : Mnementh, and answer by many java expert :   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded